# Modifying Width using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to change the width of divs using jQuery, but can't seem to be able to use expressions with the .css() method.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var docWidth = $(document).width();
var bottomWidth = $("bottom").width();

$("bottom").css("width", docWidth);

});
```

Thanks in advance, I'd appreciate all the help I can get. :3

Edit: I figured it out, thanks guys c:

Comment: what is `bottom`? is it a class name (`.bottom`) or and id (`#bottom`)?

Comment: Remember that when you use `.css('width', docWidth)` that you also need to add a unit like `px`. `.width()` returns a unitless value.

Comment: @ j08691 thats actually not true. jQuery "autocompletes" numeric values to px values.

Comment: @BasySilver - No, that's not correct at all. Read the docs. _"The difference between .css(width) and .width() is that the latter returns a unit-less pixel value (for example, 400) while the former returns a value with units intact (for example, 400px)."_

Comment: @ j08691 yes i know. And still it doesn't make a difference for jQuerys `.css()` function because it can use 400px and 400 as setter. I wasn't referring to the `.width()`function.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo mistake. I think it should be **.bottom** instead of **bottom**

Answer (score 0):

As noted in my code below:

The first alert will be undefined as you're not correctly capturing an element such as an ID or class:

$('#bottom') // $('.bottom')

However if it's a class or ID that you're trying to target adding the correct prefix will fix your issue.

If not - we'll need a little more information!

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {

    var docWidth = $(document).width();
    var bottomWidth = $("bottom").width();

    alert(docWidth);

    $("bottom").css("width", docWidth);

  });
</script>

<script>
  var test = $('.bottom').val();
  alert(test)
</script>


<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="bottom">

  </div>



</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Should work fine. Looks like you just forgot to select your element correct. With # for id and . for class. The way you have done it now is just to select an html element supposedly called "bottom"

So, change `$("bottom").css("width", docWidth);`

With `$("#bottom").css("width", docWidth);` for example to select a div or whatever with id of bottom. `<div id="bottom"></div>`

[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/EUB1ebie1QrfBeO1YGgT?p=preview)